# Android Timer Screen Dimming

Tags: android, kotlin, timer

I have a timer-like app, for which I want the screen to dim to the screen brightness minimum, after a certain amount of time but never go off.

The exact same behaviour as the android timer app does. I tried to look for the exact commands in the source code of the timer ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/deskclock)) but could not find it.

As far as I can tell when the timer is running and you are in the timer fragment the screen goes dim (darkened) 5 seconds before the screen time out time that has been set in the android settings. So for example, if you have set the screen timeout to 30 secs and you start the timer and do not touch the screen or press any button, the screen will go to minimum brightness after 25 seconds but the screen won't turn off. If you interact with the phone the screen goes to the preset brightness.

I want to replicate this exact behaviour and I think I have to use

```
window.attributes.screenBrightness == WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF
```

and

```
override fun onUserInteraction()
```

but I am not sure how to time it.

1. Where can I find this behaviour in the source code of the android timer?
2. How can I replicate this behaviour?